# About windows batch file or command shell: how to feed a string to explorer?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I want to start a explorer window from current dir in command shell.

[image]

I have try this to feed the currnet directory string to explorer, but it doesn't work

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
below is working! but it need me type the full directory string, it's not a good way, I hope it work like a unix way, that it " cd | explorer"

[image]

How to feed this stirng to explorer ?

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

after reading so many comments, I know

"start ." and "exploer ." is more convient way !

thinks for all, you are smart :)

Comment: Real easy! `start .`

Comment: @Squashman uhh - nice! I'm using `explorer .` Also `explorer %cd%` and `explorer "c:\my path\with spaces` are working for me (which is exactly lovesprings second approach).

Comment: Or you use `explorer.exe /e,"%CD%"` according to [Windows Explorer Command-Line Options](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/152457). Environment variable __CD__ contains at any time the path of current directory.

Comment: Or `start %cd%`.  Seems to be a multitude of options!

Comment: that's right. But it doesn't explain, why lovesprings second example doesn't work. @lovespring: what exactly is happening after `Explorer "c:\program files\Microsoft sdk"`?

Comment: `explorer "%cd%"` works correctly here (Windows 8.1). `start "%cd%"` don't works: it opens a cmd.exe session! **My mistake**: `start "" "%cd%"`works!